# Kernel of a 3-isogeny between two elliptic curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves

Suppose $E_1$ and $E_2$ are two elliptic curves defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ and there exists a 3-isogeny $\varphi$: $E_1 \longrightarrow E_2$. If $E_1$ has no $\mathbb{Q}$-rational point of order 3, then what is Ker $\varphi$ $?$ Is it $\mu_3$ or $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ where $\mu_3$ denotes the 3rd roots of unity $?$

Comment: What is a $3$-isogeny?

Comment: 3-isogeny means the cardinality of ker $\varphi$ is 3.

Comment: Then indeed $\mathrm{Ker} \varphi $ is $\Bbb{Z}/3$ or $\mu _3$, and both cases can occur, depending wether the kernel has a nonzero point over $\mathbb{Q}$ or not. What else do you expect?

Comment: I am expecting $\mu_3$.

Comment: To get $\mathbb{Z}/3$, just take a $\mathbb{Q}$-rational point  of order 3, for instance on the Fermat curve $x^3+y^3+z^3=0$, and mod out by the subgroup generated by this point.

Comment: Given that $E_1$ has no $\mathbb{Q}$-rational point of order 3. Then how to prove kernel is $\mu_3$ ?

Comment: Then you have no choice! There are only two possible actions of $\mathrm{Gal}(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$ over $\mathbb{Z}/3$, either trivial (corresponding to $\mathbb{Z}/3$) or through a character of order 2, giving $\mu _3$.

Comment: Can you please explain the arguments behind your second comment ?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote too hastily. In fact your group is determined by a homomorphism $\mathrm{Gal}(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})\rightarrow \{\pm 1\} $, and all such homomorphisms are possible. This means that your kernel is defined by a quadratic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, but all such extensions are allowed. If you want $\mu _3$ your kernel must be defined over $\mathbb{Q}(e^{2\pi i/3} )$.

Comment: It is easy to check that $\ker \varphi =\mu_3$ by checking that the dual isogeny has a rational $3$-torsion point in its kernel.

Comment: To expand on Chris's comment, the Weil pairing shows that $\operatorname{ker}(\phi)$ and $\operatorname{ker}(\hat\phi)$ are dual as Galois modules, so $\operatorname{ker}(\phi)=\mu_3$ if and only if $\operatorname{ker}(\hat\phi)=\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, and the latter is equivalent to the points in the kernel of $\hat\phi$ being in $\hat E(\mathbb{Q})$.

Comment: How to find out that the dual isogeny has a rational 3-torsion point in its kernel ?

Comment: sage and probably magma have implemented the algorithm to find the dual. Often a look at the isogeny class (e.g. in Cremona's tables) is enough, say because there are only two curves there.

Comment: @JoeSilverman I tried but could not find a proof of your comment explaining Chris' comment. Can you please give a reference for the fact that the kernels will be dual as Galois modules ?

Comment: @Andrew The Weil pairing for a cyclic $N$-isogeny gives a Galois equivariant perfect pairing between ker$(\phi)$ and ker$(\hat\phi)$ with values in $\mu_N$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest example is $y^2=x^3+D$, which has a 3-isogeny defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ whose kernel is $\{O,(0,\sqrt{D}),(0,-\sqrt{D})\}$. As abx pointed out, as a Galois module this kernel is defined by the quadratic extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$, which can be any quadratic extension. In general, if the kernel is $\{0,P,-P\}$, then Galios acts via $\sigma(P)=\chi(\sigma)P$, and $\chi$ is the quadratic character in abx's comment.

Comment: How do you find out the 3-isogeny defined over Q and its kernel ?

Comment: There are probably explicit formulas for 3-isogenies written down somewhere. Or you can use the method in Velu's paper, which works for cyclic $N$-isogenies (although of course it becomes infeasible in practice if $N$ gets too large). Or you can probably work it out yourself with a bit of work; I did the (admittedly easier) two isogeny case in my *Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves* book.

Comment: You can find explicit formulas for 3-isogenies in the paper by Cohen and Pazuki which is available at the link [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/0903.4963).